# Jumi variable not available in included script

Tags: php, joomla, jumi

I am using joomla 3.2 with jumi 3, here is a sample of how I call my script via jumi

> {jumi [myscript.php] [foo] [bar]}

here is myscript.php

```
<?php
    echo $jumi[0];
    echo $jumi[1];
?>
```

above script is successfully able to print the values as `foo` & `bar`

but if I modify the same to include another script ans try to get the variables in that script then it does not have any value

here is new myscript.php

```
<?php
    include 'foobar.php';
?>
```

foobar.php

```
<?php
    echo $jumi[0];
    echo $jumi[1];
?>
```

this fails to print the values. help me find if I am missing something

Comment: I am so stuck with this, please help.